# Can't connect to VS Code marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I haven't been able to connect to VS Code Marketplace for a couple of days now. I've tried restarting my laptop and reinstalling it, but the problem persists. I've also tried opening it on my other laptop and somehow got the same problem. Opening the marketplace web also refuse to connect. Why might this be?
I'm using macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and VSCode version 1.52.1

Comment: "Why might this be?" - The most likely reason is you have a network firewall that is performing content filtering.  Are you connected to a corporate network?

Comment: Nope, I'm using my home wifi as usual

Comment: What about a proxy or VPN? What url are you using exactly?

Comment: Not using any VPNs and I never mess with any proxy (I don't even know what they are). I went to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode and it won't load as well. Tho I could open it using my phone on mobile data. Is it something with my ISP then?